# Converting Currency to Word

Tags: apex

I use an apex class for converting invoice amount to words.
Below you will see the code for numbers > 1000

This code Returns 1000 as "One Thousand" but I want to make it "Thousand" only. This should apply to numbers < 2000 only. Could you point me where should I change the code? (Below convert_nn and convert_nnn are strings returning numbers < 100 and numbers < 1000, respectively.

```
    public with sharing class ConvertCurrencyToWordsEN { 

    static String[] to_19 = new string[]{ 'Zero', 'One',  'Two', 'Three', 'Four',  'Five',  'Six', 'Seven','Eight', 'Nine', 'Ten',  'Eleven', 'Twelve', 'Thirteen',  'Forteen', 'Fifteen', 'Sixteen', 'Seventeen', 'Eighteen', 'Nighteen' }; 
    static String[] tens = new string[]{ 'Twenty', 'Thirty', 'Fourty','Fifty', 'Sixty', 'Seventy', 'Eighty', 'Ninety'}; 

    static string[] denom = new string[]{ '', 
                                         'Thousand',   'Million',     'Billion',    'Trilion',    'Quatrilion', 'quintillion', 's!xtillion',   'septillion',  'octillion',   'nonillion',  'decillion',  'undecillion',   'duodecillion', 'tredecillion',  'quattuordecillion',  's!xdecillion', 'septendecillion', 'octodecillion', 'novemdecillion', 'vigintillion' }; 

// convert a value < 100 to English.   
   public static string convert_nn(integer val) { 
             if (val < 20) 
        return to_19[val]; 
      if (val == 100) 
          return 'Hundred'; 
      for (integer v = 0; v < tens.size(); v++) { 
        String dcap = tens[v]; 
        integer dval = 20 + 10 * v; 
        if (dval + 10 > val) { 
          if (Math.Mod(val,10) != 0) 
            return dcap + ' ' + to_19[Math.Mod(val,10)]; 
          return dcap; 
        }     
      } 
      return 'Should never get here, less than 100 failure'; 
    } 
    // convert a value < 1000 to english, special cased because it is the level that kicks   
    // off the < 100 special case. The rest are more general. This also allows you to  
    // get strings in the form of "forty-five hundred" if called directly.  
    public static String convert_nnn(integer val) { 
      string word = ''; 
      integer rem = val / 100; 
      integer mod = Math.mod(val,100); 
      if (rem > 0) { 
        word = to_19[rem] + ' Hundred '; 
        if (mod > 0) { 
          word += ' '; 
        } 
      } 
      if (mod > 0) { 
        word += convert_nn(mod); 
      } 
      return word; 
    } 
    public static String english_number(long val) { 
      if (val < 100) { 
        return convert_nn(val.intValue()); 
      } 
      if (val < 1000) { 
        return convert_nnn(val.intValue()); 
      } 
      for (integer v = 0; v < denom.size(); v++) { 
        integer didx = v - 1; 
        integer dval = (integer)Math.pow(1000, v); 
        if (dval > val) { 
          integer mod = (integer)Math.pow(1000, didx); 
          integer l = (integer) val / mod; 
          integer r = (integer) val - (l * mod); 
          String ret = convert_nnn(l) + ' ' + denom[didx]; 
          if (r > 0) { 
            ret += ', ' + english_number(r); 
          } 
          return ret; 
        } 
      } 
      return 'Should never get here, bottomed out in english_number'; 
    } 
  }
```

Comment: Please add convert_nn() and convert_nnn() methods

Comment: We also need to see `english_number(Integer)`...

Comment: @SantanuBoral added on the original post. thank you! I want to use wording "Thousand" only for values < 2000, e.g. for 1865 "Thousand Eight Hundred Sixty Five", but for values > 20000 , I want to use term "One Thousand", e.g. 31265, Thirty One Thousand, for, for 2000 to 20000 it's already defined as n_19+ "Thousand'

Answer (score 0):

Below code might help. Please update as per your need.

```
public class IntToEnglish {
 static List<String> to_19 = new List<String>{ 'zero',  'one',   'two',  'three', 'four',   'five',   'six',
        'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten',   'eleven', 'twelve', 'thirteen',
        'fourteen', 'fifteen', 'sixteen', 'seventeen', 'eighteen', 'nineteen' };

 static List<String> tens = new List<String>{ 'twenty', 'thirty', 'forty', 'fifty', 'sixty', 'seventy', 'eighty', 'ninety'};

 static List<String> denom = new List<String>{ '',
        'thousand',     'million',         'billion',       'trillion',       'quadrillion',
        'quintillion',  'sextillion',      'septillion',    'octillion',      'nonillion',
        'decillion',    'undecillion',     'duodecillion',  'tredecillion',   'quattuordecillion',
        'sexdecillion', 'septendecillion', 'octodecillion', 'novemdecillion', 'vigintillion' };


    public static void convertDigitTOWord(String integerVal)
    {
        integer tstValue = Integer.valueOf(integerVal);
        system.debug(english_number(tstValue ));
    }

    // convert a value < 100 to English.
    private static String convert_nn(integer val)
    {
        if (val < 20)
        {
            return to_19[val];
        }

        for (integer v = 0; v < tens.size(); v++) 
        {
            String dcap = tens[v];
            integer dval = 20 + 10 * v;
            if (dval + 10 > val) 
            {            
                if (math.mod(val,10) != 0)
                    return dcap + '-' + to_19[math.mod(val,10)];
                return dcap;
            }        
        }

        return 'XXXX';
    }

     // convert a value < 1000 to english, special cased because it is the level that kicks 
    // off the < 100 special case.  The rest are more general.  This also allows you to
    // get strings in the form of "forty-five hundred" if called directly.
    private static String convert_nnn(integer val) 
    {
        String word = '';
        integer rem = val / 100;
        integer mod = math.mod(val,100);
        if (rem > 0) {
            word = to_19[rem] + ' hundred';
            if (mod > 0) {
                word = word + ' ';
            }
        }
        if (mod > 0) {
            word = word + convert_nn(mod);
        }
        return word;
    }

    public static String english_number(integer val)
    {
        if (val < 100) 
        {
            return convert_nn(val);
        }
        if (val < 1000) 
        {
            return convert_nnn(val);
        }
        for (integer v = 0; v < denom.size(); v++) 
        {
            Integer didx = v - 1;
            Integer dval = (Math.pow(1000, v)).intValue();
            if (dval > val) {
                integer mod = (Math.pow(1000, didx)).intValue();
                integer l = val / mod;
                integer r = val - (l * mod);
                String ret = convert_nnn(l) + ' ' + denom[didx];
                if (r > 0) {
                    ret = ret + ', ' + english_number(r);
                }
                return ret;
            }
        }
       return 'XXX';
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you, I already have the code and associated triger and it works. Only problem is converting numbers between 1000 and 2000 as Thousand, instead of One Thousand. I want to use wording "Thousand" only for values < 2000, e.g. for 1865 "Thousand Eight Hundred Sixty Five", but for values > 20000 , I want to use term "One Thousand", e.g. 31265, Thirty One Thousand, for, for 2000 to 20000 it's already defined as n_19+ "Thousand'